# VS2019: "The installer manifest failed signature validation"

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to install Visual Studio Community 2019. However, every time I try to run the installer, it stops immediately with the following error: "The installer manifest failed signature validation." How can I fix this?

For reference, I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this?

Before I tried any of the solutions, I would simply, download the Visual Studio 2019 Community installer again.  If that does not work try each solution in order.

`Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> System cryptography`

Disable: **Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing**

[image]

However, this typically happens when the certificates used to sign the installer, are not trusted.  Be sure you are installing the current Visual Studio 2019 build.  You also must verify if you have all available Windows 7 updates installed.

Source: [When the setup start, I receive the message "The package manifest failed signature validation"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3983/when-the-setup-start-i-receive-the-message-the-pac.html)

If the certificates are not trusted, mount the Visual Studio 2019 ISO, and import the certificates in the appropriate folder.  This problem was fixed more then 2 years ago, so if your system is current, and you are using the current Visual Studio 2019 installer, you will have to import the certificates yourself.

You should also update your system's certificates.  You will need the [rootsupd](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/rootsupd.exe) in order to acomplish that.

> 1. Extract the contents
>
> > `rootsupd.exe /c /t:C:\temp\newroot`
>
> 2. From within the directory, in an elevated command prompt, issue the following commands.
>
> > ```
> > updroots.exe authroots.sst
> >
> > updroots.exe updroots.sst
> >
> > updroots.exe -l roots.sst
> >
> > updroots.exe -d delroots.sst
> > ```

Source: [VS2017 installer - the package manifest failed signature validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160085/vs2017-installer-the-package-manifest-failed-signature-validation)

[image]